# Need good ideas about improving any Linux service

Tags: linux, memory, process-management, linux-kernel

I have a project assigned to me by OS teacher to choose any Linux service and improve it. Currently I am totally blank in this. I am not sure which service should I use which can easily be implemented and my project just get finished. Can you guys help me out to choose a service which can easily be improved and implemented?

One idea which is in my mind right now is that currently we can stop any process (just consider client processes to keep things easy) but I think there is no option to pause the process? So i am thinking to implement this so that user can pause their running process.

Comment: "Pausing" can be done with `SIGSTOP`/`SIGCONT` (not just on Linux).

Comment: how about process state migration to another host? and then resume the process on the other from where it was stopped.. purely an independent tool to do it. Would come handy incase the host on which the process is hosed and you want to transport the running process to another as is. Just a thought to augment yours.

Comment: Is this "service" in a low-level OS sense? If not, people have been thinking about merging `cron` and `at` for ages but nobody has done it, or you could have a similar service which uses or generates `ics` files, so you can see your cronjobs in your calendar.

Comment: systematization in newly tools, i.e in keys modules parameters to commands, documentation..